# Menu link that is author nodeid specific

Tags: hooks, navigation

When a user creates an account i have a rule that creates a node and set them as author for it.

I need a user specific link in the menu that varries from user to user.

User 1 may need the link: "Edit your node" -> Links to node/1/edit
User 2 may need the link: "Edit your node" -> Links to node/5/edit

So its something like:

If content type = FOO, and node author = logged in user, show link "Edit your node" that links to -> node/%/edit.

Answer (score 0):

You should use tokens in your menu-item for it to change dynamically. Install [Menu Token](https://www.drupal.org/project/menu_token) module. From the module page-

> Menu Token allows to use both global tokens and entity ones: node, user, term, etc.

Then allow your menu path to use tokens and set something along `node/[node-id]/edit` as your path.